# Convert PDF to Docx/Rtf with Css formatting

Tags: php, pdf-conversion

I want to convert the pdf file into Docx or RTF format with CSS formatting.

I tried following libraries:

```
1. PHPDocx       - It is paid.
2. PHPvsWord     - The repo is too old.
3. PHPWord       - It has issues with table ( Doesn't support table with CSS ).
4. Html-Docx-js  - It also doesn't support CSS.
```

Is there any open source library which supports conversion with CSS formatting?

Any help would be highly appreciated.